# "What the guy did was comfort her until she stopped crying"

Tags: grammaticality

> What the guy did was comfort her until she stopped crying.

Is this grammatically correct?

I was trying to make a story, and I couldn't move on on this part, "she was crying when the guy saw her, and what the guy did was, he comforted her until she stopped crying".

Answer (score 0):

It's correct as is, but barely. It would be a little better grammatically to write

> What the guy did was to  comfort her until she stopped crying.

That said, in a story I would expect your sentence from a somewhat poorly educated first person narrator talking about some other guy. It would not be proper English from an author. The very use of "guy" reminds me of Damon Runyon:

> Runyon's short stories are told in the first person by a protagonist
> who is never named, and whose role is unclear; he knows many gangsters
> and does not appear to have a job, but he does not admit to any
> criminal involvement, and seems to be largely a bystander. He
> describes himself as "being known to one and all as a guy who is just
> around"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damon_Runyon#Literary_style

Answer (score -1):

In spoken English this wouldn't be very unnatural. It would probably be used as a contrast to some other action, for example, "I thought he would drop her and run. But what the guy *did* was, he comforted her until she stopped crying."

But in written English this isn't strictly proper and it makes the sentence run on; it sounds like something that would be said by someone without a lot of education. It could be shortened by saying "The guy comforted her until she stopped crying."

Comment: I was trying to make a story, and I couldn't move on on this part, "she was crying when the guy saw her, and what the guy did was, he comforted her until she stopped crying"  can you correct the whole thing for me. Sorry for my poor grammar BTW  I'm just starting to learn.

Comment: @EraserHead I would just take out the clause altogether: "She was crying when the guy saw her, and he comforted her until she stopped."

Comment: Could you guys explain why it was this heavily downvoted?